# Live face detection in Android

Tags: android, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement face detection with the camera preview in Android. Does someone know any (open-source) libraries that can help me do this?

Answer (score 5):

[OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary) library has the Android port and provides face detection as one of samples for Android platform. Here is [a tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html) to start with.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a Java binding to OpenCV with Android support.  It also has supports a number of other Computer Vision libraries.

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have to use an external opencv library?

Could you not just use the built in android one? 
android.media.FaceDetector;

Comment: This can detect the face but nut not the live-ness.

Answer (score 0):

If your device has some Qualcomm hardware, you can use the brand new library FastCV : https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv
API is here : https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/fastcv/api/index.html